# Sublime 3 HTML formatter puts everything on new line with Blade

Tags: sublimetext3, code-formatting, laravel-blade

I'm working on a Laravel project and using Blade for templating. My problem is Sublime puts every HTML tag on next line when I save the file. Autoformat on save is on. Here is an example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="data[month_number]">
    <option value="1">
        January
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        February
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        March
    </option>
    <option value="4">
        April
    </option>
    <option value="5">
        May
    </option>
    <option value="6">
        June
    </option>
    <option value="7">
        July
    </option>
    <option value="8">
        August
    </option>
    <option value="9">
        September
    </option>
    <option value="10">
        October
    </option>
    <option value="11">
        November
    </option>
    <option value="12">
        December
    </option>
</select>
```

whereas it should be:

```
<select class="form-control" name="data[month_number]">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Here is my HTML CodeFormatter setting:

```
"codeformatter_html_options": {
    "syntaxes": "html,blade,asp,xml,php", // Syntax names which must process HTML formatter
    "format_on_save": true, // Format on save. Either a boolean (true/false) or a string regexp tested on filename. Example : "^((?!.min.|vendor).)*$"
    "formatter_version": "bs4", // Which formatter to use. Current options are "bs4" and "regexp". If an error occurs while loading the bs4 formatter, the regexp formatter will automatically be used
    "indent_size": 4, // indentation size
    "indent_char": " ", // Indentation character
    "indent_with_tabs": false, // Indent with one tab (overrides indent_size and indent_char options)
    "exception_on_tag_mismatch": false, // If the last closing tag is not at the same indentation level as the first opening tag, there's probably a tag mismatch in the file
    "expand_javascript": false, // (Under construction) Expand JavaScript inside of <script> tags (also affects CSS purely by coincidence)
    "expand_tags": false, // Expand tag attributes onto new lines
    "minimum_attribute_count": 2, // Minimum number of attributes needed before tag attributes are expanded to new lines
    "first_attribute_on_new_line": false, // Put all attributes on separate lines from the tag (only uses 1 indentation unit as opposed to lining all attributes up with the first)
    "preserve_newlines": true, // whether existing line breaks should be preserved,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 2, // maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk
    "reduce_empty_tags": false, // Put closing tags on same line as opening tag if there is no content between them
    "reduce_whole_word_tags": false, // Put closing tags on same line as opening tag if there is whole word between them
    "custom_singletons": "" // Custom singleton tags for various template languages outside of the HTML5 spec
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reduce_whole_word_tags` option:

```
"reduce_whole_word_tags": false, // Put closing tags on same line as opening tag if there is whole word between them
```

You have it set to `false`. Set it to `true`.